# using <script setup> eslint and vetur warning even when I use them in template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Im using `<script setup>` in vue 3, but I get those warnings on my methods because I no longer need to return them.

Any idea why it gives me those warnings?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I got the same problem and switched to `vite` as my bundler. This [laravel introduction to vue3 and vite](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-vue-3/episodes/1) helped me a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is 4 months later, but it may help someone else who has the same problem.

You didn't include what the warnings actually were, but I believe they were related to unused variables and functions (because graying out a identifier is how VS Code marks it as unused, and because I have had the same issue myself).

**This is due to [Vetur not supporting `<script setup>` yet](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/2296).**

[Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnsoncodehk.volar) is now the recommended VS Code extension for Vue (see [this comment of Evan's](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/378#discussioncomment-1158805) and [the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#ide-support)). Vetur is now deprecated and [will enter "End of Life by the end of 2023"](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/3476).